# Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.2.1.

Tags: python, cuda

How should I solve this error?

```
$ python tensorboard_viz.py
/scratch/sjn-p3/anaconda/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/h5py/__init__.py:36: FutureWarning: Conversion of the second argument of issubdtype from `float` to `np.floating` is deprecated. In future, it will be treated as `np.float64 == np.dtype(float).type`.
  from ._conv import register_converters as _register_converters
2018-10-24 19:49:39.925967: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-10-24 19:49:40.093637: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1411] Found device 0 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:05:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.03GiB
2018-10-24 19:49:40.238084: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1411] Found device 1 with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.6705
pciBusID: 0000:06:00.0
totalMemory: 10.92GiB freeMemory: 10.76GiB
2018-10-24 19:49:40.238960: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1490] Adding visible gpu devices: 0, 1
2018-10-24 19:49:41.287661: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:971] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2018-10-24 19:49:41.287712: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977]      0 1 
2018-10-24 19:49:41.287733: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 0:   N Y 
2018-10-24 19:49:41.287748: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:990] 1:   Y N 
2018-10-24 19:49:41.288287: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 with 9694 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:05:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-24 19:49:41.434704: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1103] Created TensorFlow device (/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:1 with 10405 MB memory) -> physical GPU (device: 1, name: GeForce GTX 1080 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0, compute capability: 6.1)
2018-10-24 19:49:44.406950: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:343] Loaded runtime CuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.2.1.  CuDNN library major and minor version needs to match or have higher minor version in case of CuDNN 7.0 or later version. If using a binary install, upgrade your CuDNN library.  If building from sources, make sure the library loaded at runtime is compatible with the version specified during compile configuration.
Segmentation fault
```

Can you please provide the correct commands for doing so?

Comment: even i have the same issue....please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41005249/what-does-the-error-loaded-runtime-cudnn-library-5005-but-source-was-compiled/41008150#41008150

Answer (score 5):

I had this same problem, following approach works fine

```
pip3 uninstall tensorflow-gpu

pip3 install tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0
```

Note: I am using 'pip3' because I was working with python-3.x, you can use 'pip' instead if you are working with python-2.x

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I solved it by installing the CuDNN library suggested in the traceback (Loaded runtime cuDNN library: 7.0.5 but source was compiled with: 7.2.1.)

I replaced the cuDNN version with cuDNN v7.2.1 (August 7, 2018), for CUDA 9.2 and it works for me. This way you can maintain your tensorflow-gpu version.

You can get the library from the cuDNN Archive: https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-archive

Ensure your whole configuration matches one of the tested built configurations: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows#tested_build_configurations
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations

Answer (score 1):

Please type this in terminal....problem is with Tensorflow version

sudo pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu==1.9.0